# Swift UI how to append messages in a List or Scrollable view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a binded string called `fullLogMessage` this string gets updated from various callbacks in different ViewControllers. I have got this to show the log messages in the Swift UI View.

What I have is:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading content: { 
  Text("Logs")
   .font(.footnote).fontWeight(.medium)
  Textfield("Log messages here", text: $fullLogMessage)
   .font(.custom("FONT_NAME", size: 12))
}
```

What happens is this textfield text is just replaced with a new `fullLogMessage`. What I would like is for the current appended message to be visible, possibly have two messages showing at a time, but have the messages append so previous log messages are visible by scrolling.

I'm trying to use `ScrollView` by doing this:

```
ScrollView { 
 ForEach($fullLogMessage) { logMessage in 
  VStack { 
     Text(logMessage)
    } 
  }
}
```

Just to test it out and then build it like the one I have above, but I'm getting errors on that code showing `'cannot convert value of type Binding<String> to expected argument type 'Range<Int>''`

Not sure if I'm doing this the right way.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use `$` for the variable in the `ForEach` closure too. Now you can use `$logMessage` as a `Binding`, or `logMessage` as a regular get-only value.

I'm also using an array here, so you can actually have the logs split up properly and can be iterated over. `[LogMessage]` is used rather than `[String]` so the rows are uniquely identified, rather than identifying by the log message/string (which may not be unique).

Full example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fullLogMessages: [LogMessage] = []

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Button("New log", action: addLogMessage)

            ForEach($fullLogMessages) { $logMessage in
                TextField("Log", text: $logMessage.message)
            }
        }
    }

    private func addLogMessage() {
        let new = LogMessage("Log #\(fullLogMessages.count + 1)")
        fullLogMessages.append(new)
    }
}
```

```
struct LogMessage: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var message: String

    init(_ message: String) {
        self.message = message
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already have my Log View in place, generates a date, takes in an Id and sets the message. Then I use a getFullLogMessage method to return all this concatenated into a binded string $fullLogMessage. All I need is for this $fullLogMessage to be appended each time, there is no action from a button as I'm using updateUIViewController to manage the updates.

Comment: @Sam Well why don't you just change your other code? Concatenating the log messages is possible but really not the best idea. It also make the code unnecessarily complex when you could just represent it with an array instead, and all the info for each log you need is in `LogMessage`.

Comment: I can change it, but I've spent time developing it now and having all the log messages set between the views. Is there a way of appending it from a binded string rather than array?

Comment: @Sam How do you concatenate the log messages, are they split by a certain character or something?

Comment: @Sam While trying this I am seeing even more how much of a bad idea this is. Because you aren't identifying by something like `UUID()` like I did, and identifying by the string, the ID is different when you change the text. Meaning you can only type/delete one character at a time before the `TextField` loses focus because it is a completely new view to it.

Comment: the logs are just simple logs. No need to keep track of them, just want to see the latest log message and have it scrollable to view previous logs. The logging won't even be a large number, the journey of the logs are simply date, message showing sent, response received, callbacks etc through views.